# How to use filter method to return another property inside the object that passed the filter test?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, array.prototype.map

I am attempting to iterate over an array of objects using the `filter` and `map` methods in order to return an array with all objects that include the property name `note` where `note` is `==` to 'B' (`var note = 'B'`). The problem is that `filter` only returns '`note: 'B'`' from the object and I need it to return the other property in the object: `functionCall`. Filter returns only '`note: 'B'`' but what I need is either `functionCall: getSoundB('audio/34.wav', 1, false)` or `note: 'B', functionCall: getSoundB('audio/34.wav', 1, false)`.

Here is my example program:

```js
function getSoundB(a, b, c) {
  // does stuff
};

var potentialThunderSounds = [{
    note: 'B',
    functionCall: getSoundB('audio/34.wav', 1, false)
  },
  {
    note: 'B',
    functionCall: getSoundB('audio/35.wav', 1, false)
  },
  {
    note: 'A',
    functionCall: getSoundB('audio/36.wav', 1, false)
  }
];

function filterForMatchingNotes(arrayName) {
  return arrayName
    .filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.note == note;
    })
    .map(function(obj) {
      return obj.functionCall;
    });
}

var note = 'B';
var tempFilterArray = filterForMatchingNotes(potentialThunderSounds);

console.log('tempFilterArray.length: ' + tempFilterArray.length);
console.log('tempFilterArray: ' + tempFilterArray);
console.log('tempFilterArray string: ' + JSON.stringify(tempFilterArray));
```

When I run my program, the array is populated with two empty properties. The reason seems to be because `filter` only returned '`note: 'B'`' which doesn't include the property `functionCall`. So when `map` goest to look for the property name 'functionCall,' it doesn't exist.

I attempted to restructure the objects in my array as follows so that `functionCall` would be within the property `note`, but that didn't work as it looks like a property value can't be an object:

```js
var potentialThunderSounds = [{
  note: {'B', functionCall: getSoundB('audio/34.wav', 1, false)}
}];
```

Here is additional code that shows how the function getSound is used. I'm using Howler.js ([Howler Docs](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#documentation)):

```js
/* 
when getSound is called, it plays an audio file based on the params passed in.
*/
function getSoundB(soundFileName, sampleVolume, loop) { 
  var volumeMax = getRandom(optionNames[objectName].volumeMin, optionNames[objectName].volumeMax);
  var volume = Math.floor(volumeMax * optionNames[objectName].objectVolume * sampleVolume / 100);
  return new Howl({
    src: [soundFileName],
    autoplay: false,
    loop: loop,
    volume: volume,
    fade: 0
  });
}

/* 
thunderPlayer accepts an integer as a parameter. It will then decide which specific sounds (listed as function calls inside the array potentialThunderSounds) will be played. It will push those sounds (aka function calls with a sound file as a parameter) into a temporary array so it can be called at a specific time later.  
*/
function thunderPlayer(numberOfSoundsToPlay) {
  var soundSequence = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < numberOfSoundsToPlay; x++) {
    var soundIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * (optionNames[objectName].potentialThunderSounds.length - 1));
    soundSequence.push(optionNames[objectName].potentialThunderSounds[soundIndex]); // this pushes the the getSound function calls (which are elements in the array potentialThunderSounds) into an array so that they can be called at specific times later
  }
  playSoundIfThereIsOne();

  function playSoundIfThereIsOne() {
    var currentSound = soundSequence[0];
    if (currentSound != undefined) { // stops call when there is no sound 
      currentSound.stereo(stereoPosition(objectName));
      currentSound.play();
      soundSequence.shift();
      currentSound.once('end', playSoundIfThereIsOne);
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Notes on the solution.

After working through @MiroslavGlamuzina's solution, it seems to solve my problem. When filtering for the specific element in an array of objects using his code, it does appear to return the whole object as I was hoping to do (and not simply that specific name/value pair in the object that I was filtering for).

I found the following example code which also illustrates this point:

```js
var heroes = [{
    name: 'Batman',
    franchise: 'DC'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ironman',
    franchise: 'Marvel'
  },
  {
    name: 'Thor',
    franchise: 'Marvel'
  },
  {
    name: 'Superman',
    franchise: 'DC'
  }
];

var marvelHeroes = heroes.filter(function(hero) {
  return hero.franchise == 'Marvel';
});

console.log(marvelHeroes);
```

In the example, the elements "franchise" are filtered for those including the string "Marvel", but the whole object is returned: `{name: 'Thor', franchise: 'Marvel'}'.

I had an additional consideration which was that one of the element values for each object in my array was a function call (e.g., `getSoundB('audio/34.wav', 1, false)`), and I wanted to make sure that the function wasn't invoked/executed (I hope I'm using call and invoke correctly here?). In my tests in my actual program, it doesn't appear that these function calls are being invoked during the filter process (which is what I want).

Comment: The problem is that the `functionCall` properties are set to the result of calling `getSoundB` which return `undefined` which means that `filterForMatchingNotes` will always return an empty array or an array with all `undefined` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filterForMatchingNotes()` is not returning what you expect it to return, you are returning the value of a function that returns `undefined` and not the object as a whole.

```js
const potentialThunderSounds = [{
    note: 'B',
    functionCall: getSoundB('audio/34.wav', 1, false)
  },
  {
    note: 'B',
    functionCall: getSoundB('audio/35.wav', 1, false)
  },
  {
    note: 'A',
    functionCall: getSoundB('audio/36.wav', 1, false)
  }
];

function getSoundB(a, b, c) {
  // does stuff
};

function filterForMatchingNotes(arrayName, note) {
  return arrayName
    .filter(obj => obj.note === note);
}

let note = 'B';
let tempFilterArray = filterForMatchingNotes(potentialThunderSounds, note);

console.log(tempFilterArray);
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Is there a way, or method, to return the object as I want it instead of the return/result of the function `getSoundB` being called? Or, maybe you've done that in your example. I'll have to look harder at your code example.

Comment: Just return what you need to in `getSoundB` and the value will be there when you log it :)

Comment: I think the problem is that I want to add the function calls (e.g. `getSoundB('audio/34.wav', 1, false)`) to the array and not its return value. This way I can call the function and get a different result later. But maybe I'm doing things the wrong way? My program already works by referencing the calls in the array. I'm trying to keep that logic but filter out some of the calls/properties from the array that aren't need at a given time.

Comment: Can you update your post to provide a more complete picture of what is happening in `getSoundB` please

Comment: I just added the getSound function and related code to my question above with some descriptions of how it is being implemented. Thanks.